# Flutter, RSA decrypt with two private Keys

Tags: encryption, flutter, dart, rsa, end-to-end

I was looking for a way to implement end-to-end encryption in my flutter app. I can generate key pairs, encrypt and decrypt strings, but I need a way to decrypt string with two separate private keys....

Example: I want Alice to encrypt a message and send it to Bob (obviously Bob will decrypt it with his private key) but then the encrypted message will be stored in a database so there is no way for Alice to see her message after encrypting it.

Here is the function to encrypt and decrypt a string:

```
String encrypt(String plaintext, RSAPublicKey publicKey) {
  var cipher = new RSAEngine()
    ..init(true, new PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(publicKey));
  var cipherText = cipher.process(new Uint8List.fromList(plaintext.codeUnits));

  return new String.fromCharCodes(cipherText);
}

String decrypt(String ciphertext, RSAPrivateKey privateKey) {
  var cipher = new RSAEngine()
    ..init(false, new PrivateKeyParameter<RSAPrivateKey>(privateKey));
  var decrypted = cipher.process(new Uint8List.fromList(ciphertext.codeUnits));

  return new String.fromCharCodes(decrypted);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you instead need a key agreement scheme like Diffe Hellman. Alice and Bob can derive a shared secret from their private key and the other party's public key. Only Alice or Bob can encrypt or decrypt as only they know both one private key and one public key.

Comment: *so there is no way for alice to see her message after encrypting it...* So why is it that you need two private keys to be able to decrypt the message if you're only encrypting to bob?

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk i am creating chat app, So if i store the encrypted message bob can get the message from the database and decrypt it, but alice cannot do that.

Comment: @RichardHeap do you know any good resources for this key agreement method ?

Comment: Ok. Do you want alice to be able to decrypt the message?

Comment: @RichardHeap i've been thinking about another way to do this, what if i **encrypt the message twice** ( with Alice public key & with Bob public key ) store both encrypted Strings in a map**('alice_id' : 'encryptedTextForAlice', 'bob_id': 'encryptedTextForBob')** in my database, that way Alice and Bob can build their own copy of the chat. i know it's not efficient, But what do you think about it ?

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Yes, please check my suggestion, What do you think about it?

Comment: You are close. What you really should be using is [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). You generate an AES-GCM key k and encrypt your message using AES-GCM with key k. Then you encrypt k using the public key of bob and again using the public key of alice. Then you concatenate all three of these piece together and send/store that as the encrypted message.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk , ok i understood how that work, but how can i make sure that Alice and Bob have generated the same AES-GCM key, the key generation will take place in their Phone!!

Comment: Bob doesn't generate the key, Alice does. So if AES(k, M) is the encryption of message M using AES and key k, and RSA_E(person, k) is the encryption of key k using RSA with *person's* public key, then the final encrypted message that Alice creates, sends to Bob, and saves in the database is RSA_E(Alice, k) concat RSA_E(Bob, k) concat AES(k, M). Bob doesn't need to generate k, instead he *recovers* k by decrypting RSA_E(Bob, k) with his private key. Alice can do this as well.